# Arduino Uno keeps looping on setup() everytime I press a specific button on the remote

Tags: arduino-uno, ir, remote-control

I'm trying to decode my Panasonic television remote using the IR_RECEIVE sketch below.

When I press the remote's buttons it works fine and Iget the values, except from when I press the power button - the setup() function executes.

This is the code:

```
/* Raw IR decoder sketch!

This sketch/program uses the Arduno and a PNA4602 to
decode IR received. This can be used to make a IR receiver
(by looking for a particular code)
or transmitter (by pulsing an IR LED at ~38KHz for the
durations detected

Code is public domain, check out www.ladyada.net and adafruit.com
for more tutorials!
*/

#define IRpin_PIN      PIND
#define IRpin          2
#define MAXPULSE 65000
#define RESOLUTION 20 

uint16_t pulses[100][2];  // pair is high and low pulse 
uint8_t currentpulse = 0; // index for pulses we're storing

void setup(void) {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Ready to decode IR!");
}

void loop(void) {
    uint16_t highpulse, lowpulse;  // temporary storage timing
    highpulse = lowpulse = 0; // start out with no pulse length

    while (IRpin_PIN & (1 << IRpin)) {
        highpulse++;
        delayMicroseconds(RESOLUTION);

        if ((highpulse >= MAXPULSE) && (currentpulse != 0)) {
            printpulses();
            currentpulse = 0;
            return;
        }
    }
    pulses[currentpulse][0] = highpulse;

    while (!(IRpin_PIN & _BV(IRpin))) {
        lowpulse++;
        delayMicroseconds(RESOLUTION);
        if ((lowpulse >= MAXPULSE) && (currentpulse != 0)) {
            printpulses();
            currentpulse = 0;
            return;
        }
    }
    pulses[currentpulse][1] = lowpulse;

    currentpulse++;
}

void printpulses(void) {
    Serial.println("\n\r\n\rReceived: \n\rOFF \tON");
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < currentpulse; i++) {
        Serial.print("delayMicroseconds(");
        Serial.print(pulses[i][0] * RESOLUTION, DEC);
        Serial.println(");");

        Serial.print("pulseIR(");
        Serial.print(pulses[i][1] * RESOLUTION, DEC);
        Serial.println(");");
    }
}
```

This is the output:

> Ready to decode IR!
>
> Received:
>
> OFF   ON
>   delayMicroseconds(34724);
>   pulseIR(3600);
>   delayMicroseconds(1800);
>   ......
>   delayMicroseconds(1340);
>   pulseIR(460);
>   delayMicroseconds(1360);
>   pulseIR(460);
>   Ready to decode IR!
>   Ready to decode IR!

The last 2 rows appeared when I pressed the power button (twice).
The rows above appears when I press any other button.

I played around with the Arduino and the remote, I might have done something to cause this. The first time I tried it - it worked fine.

I tried resetting and re-uploading.

Sorry if the post is too long or not informative enough - I'm new to this and not really sure what kind of information to provide.

Comment: the chip resets on some error

Comment: try larger array `uint16_t pulses[150][2];`

Answer (score 1):

How high can `currentpulse` get before it is reset to zero? It is used an array index and if it gets larger than the (number of array elements-1), your code will write outside of the array.

Can the array be so far over-written that it grows into the stack area? That could definitely cause a reset, or reset-like behavior.